# Invalid data type PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the following-

```
 TYPE station_record_type IS RECORD
    (
        station_code  t_stations.station_code%TYPE,
        city_name d_cities.city_name%TYPE,
        station_name d_stations.station_name%TYPE,
        state_name gis_states.state_name%TYPE,
       country_name d_countries.country_name%TYPE,
        record_type pls_integer
    );

    TYPE stations_table_type IS TABLE OF station_record_type
       INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;


  o_stations_to_retrieve      stations_table_type
```

I am trying to sort the collection  using --

```
    SELECT CAST (MULTISET (SELECT station_record_type (station_code,
                                                         city_name,
                                                         station_name,
                                                         state_name,
                                                         country_name,
                                                         record_type)
                               FROM TABLE (o_stations_to_retrieve)
                           ORDER BY country_name,
                                    state_name,
                                    city_name,
                                    record_type,
                                    station_name ) AS stations_table_type)
      INTO o_stations_to_retrieve
      FROM DUAL;
```

I received the error Invalid data type for stations_table_type. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Oracle using package defined types in this way is not supported. You need to create database sql object type in the following way: Note that declaration column%type is not supported here ( neither INDEX BY clause)

```
CREATE TYPE station_record_type IS OBJECT
(
    station_code  varchar2(100),
    city_name varchar2(100),
    station_name varchar2(100),
    state_name varchar2(100),
   country_name varchar2(100),
    record_type number
 )
 /
  create   TYPE stations_table_type IS TABLE OF station_record_type;
```

Now you can implement your sorting select using these types.